# How can I pad a nested list in python?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, padding, nested-lists

I have a very long nested list with the following irregular structure:

```
[[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
 [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
 [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
  ...]
```

I would like to pad it with -10 at the beginning to look like below:

```
[[[-10,-10,-10], [-10,-10,-10], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
 [[-10,-10,-10], [-10,-10,-10], [-10, -10, -10], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
 [[-10,-10,-10], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],
  ...]
```

Where the second level of the nested list has 5 elements, each with 3 numbers.

I cannot use np.pad, because I cannot convert the irregular length list to an array.

Thank you in advance as I am a beginner.

Comment: How do we determine how many sets of `[-10, -10, -10]` we need to pad each "row" with?

Comment: Until the total number of elements in each "row" is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of lists of 3-element lists.
You want to make it a list of 5-element lists of 3-element lists.
If there are not enough elements in a second-level list, you want to add `[-10, -10, -10]` at the beginning of the list.

```
new_list = []
for second_level in old_list:
    new_second_level = [[-10, -10, -10]] * (5-len(second_level)) + second_level 
    new_list.append(new_second_level)
```

I assumed that there is no 6-or-more-element list in the second level.
Note that you can replicate a list multiple times using the * operator.
As examples,

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> [[1, 2, 3]] * 3
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

In a short version using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

```
new_list = [[[-10, -10, -10]] * (5 - len(second_level)) + second_level for second_level in old_list]
```